# Change the SRC of a Google map (quick map services)

Tags: mapping, utm

I´m defining a watershed basin using QGIS. I have to migrate the data I collected on QGIS to a third part Application. All transfer of data is doing through DXF files. I use the quick map services to set the satellite photo of the local and I transfer also the contour lines. It happens that the synchronization is not being done correctly. The contour lines are put a little out (about 50 pixels) from the correct place on the map.
I detected that the SRC of the map is different of the contour lines SRC. The contour lines are on a UTM SRC. I´m trying to change the SRC of the map but I haven´t found a tool or a procedure to do that.
Is there any way or tool to do that?

Obs: I tried change the SRC on menu and raster->reproject coordinates on the image layer without success
On QGIS the overlay of the image and the contour lines are correct.